# Finding the smallest missing positive number in an array

Tags: java, array, integer

Any suggestions to improve?

```
public class FindSmallestMissingPositive {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[] = {3,5,4,-1,1,-1,0};
        System.out.println("Smallest Missing positive : "+ findSmPositive(a));
    }

    public static int findSmPositive(int input[]){
        int min = input[0];
        int max= input[0];

        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
            set.add(input[i]);

            if(input[i]<min){
                min = input[i];
            }
            if(input[i]>max){
                max = input[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
            if(i>0 && !set.contains(i)){
                return i;
            }
            else continue;

        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: if min is more than 1, or max is less than 1, then result should be 1, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bugs

The implementation incorrectly gives -1 for all these input:

- `[0]` should return 1
- `[1]` should return 2
- `[2]` should return 1
- `[0,2,2,1,1]` should return 3
- `[1,2,2,1,3,1,0,4,0]` should return 5

#### Improving the algorithm

The algorithm you used is \$O(n)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ space.
If you don't mind modifying the input array,
then you could reuse it as the storage,
making the algorithm \$O(1)\$ space.

Consider this alternative algorithm:

- If the array is empty, return 1
- Loop over the array indexes

  - While `input[i] - 1` is a valid array index *and* not in the correct position, *and* `input[input[i] - 1]` is not in the correct position, then swap the elements `i` and `input[i] - 1`.
- Loop over the array indexes again, and when you find a value not in the correct position, then return `i + 1`.
- Return the last value + 1.

The logic behind this algorithm:

- Swap elements into the correct position to get a sequence of positive integers 1, 2, 3, ...
- Ignore values that cannot be in this array (<= 0 or too high index)
- The beginning of the array will be filled with correct sequence values, gaps will be filled with junk, and the second looping pass will short-circuit on the first incorrect value

#### Strange coding style

Although these type declarations compile, they are not recommended:

> ```
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>
> public static int findSmPositive(int input[]) {
> ```

The recommended writing style:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

public static int findSmPositive(int[] input) {
```

Also,
the code formatting style is not great, at many places it's too compact.
I suggest to copy paste into an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse and use the auto-formatting function to reformat nicely.

#### Testing your improvements

The problem description seems to match this one on leetcode.
After you implement your improvements,
I suggest posting there to verify the correctness of your implementation.

https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/

Answer (score 5):

#### Possible bug

> ```
> int min = input[0];
> int max= input[0];
> ```

is going to explode if you pass an empty array. This is not what I would expect from the method. The smallest missing positive number in an empty array is 0, because 0 is not the array and it is the smallest positive number.

Then, you actually do not need to store the minimum and the maximum: since we want the smallest positive numbers, we can start searching from 0, and increment while the array contains it.

#### Use enhanced for loop

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
>     set.add(input[i]);
>     // ...
> }
> ```

When you're iterating over an array, or an `Iterable`, and you don't need the index, it is simpler to use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (int element : input) {
    set.add(element);
    // ...
}
```

#### Don't bother with negative elements

We're searching for the smallest positive numbers, so we can ignore negative ones. So inside:

> ```
> for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
>     if(i>0 && !set.contains(i)){
>         return i;
>     }
>     else continue;
>
> }
> ```

There is no need to start at the minimum: we can start at 0. Furthermore, instead of using a `for` loop, it would be cleaner to use a `while` loop:

```
int smallestPositive = 0;
while (set.contains(smallestPositive)) {
    smallestPositive++;
}
return smallestPositive;
```

This is a lot shorter and also clearer: while the set of all the numbers in the array contains our attempt, increment it. This will terminate when we find the smallest one.

A small memory improvement, if there are a lot of negative numbers, would be to not store negative numbers in the set in the first place. It doesn't hurt performance since `contains` will still be constant-time, but there will be less elements in it.

Comment: +1, although I believe the smallest *positive* (not non-negative) integer is usually 1. OP uses this definition as well.

Answer (score 4):

#### Favor interfaces over implementations

> ```
>         HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
> ```

Consider

```
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Everything else stays the same.  Now if you want to change from a `HashSet` to another `Set` type, you can just change it one place.  Not so big a deal here, but when you start passing them, using the interface can simplify later changes greatly.

#### Toss bad data early

At the end, you check that the number is positive.  Why wait?

> ```
>         for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
>             set.add(input[i]);
>
>             if(input[i]<min){
>                 min = input[i];
>             }
>             if(input[i]>max){
>                 max = input[i];
>             }
>         }
> ```

If you check here, you have fewer elements to check later, and you don't have to worry about a negative `min`.

```
        for (int element : input) {
            if (element < 0) {
                min = 0;
                continue;
            }

            set.add(element);

            if (element < min) {
                min = element;
            }

            if (element > max) {
                max = element;
            }
        }
```

Note that the

```
                min = 0;
```

is just there to cover sets like `{-5, 5}`.  Your code will return `1` in that case.  This preserves that.

#### Know your boundaries

> ```
>         for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
>             if(i>0 && !set.contains(i)){
>                 return i;
>             }
>             else continue;
>
>         }
> ```

You don't have to check `min` and `max`.  The set will always contain `max`.  And `min` can only be out of the set if it is `0`, which doesn't need to be checked.  So

```
        for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (!set.contains(i)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
```

Now every value it checks has a chance to be the answer.

I removed the `continue`, as it didn't do anything in this loop.

As I said earlier, the `i > 0` check is unnecessary here, as `min + 1` will always be positive.  The smallest value for `min` is 0, and we add one to start.